# c# wpf edit button at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a button with my mouse events like going from one point A and sizing with the mouse.

Now when my Mouse input is released i want to draw the 4 points of the Button(TopLeftCorner,TopRighTCorner,ButtomLeft, Buttomright) and when clicked on one point adjust the size or move the button

Here's my code for drawing the button but I can't draw the 4 points when my mouse is released.

```
    private Point startPoint;
    private Button rectangle;

    private void PaintSurface_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        //Recupere la position de la souris 
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(paintSurface);

        //Instantie un nouveau Button 
        rectangle = new Button
        {
            BorderBrush = Brushes.LightBlue,
            //TO be given an name for the zone 
            Content = "Zone",
            Name = "Zone",
        };


        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, startPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, startPoint.X);
        paintSurface.Children.Add(rectangle);
    }





    private void PaintSurface_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            return;
          //  Point point = new Point();
          //  point.X = x;
            //point.Y = y;
          //  rectangle.PointFromScreen(point);
           // MessageBox.Show(point.ToString());




        var pos = e.GetPosition(paintSurface);


        var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
        var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);


        var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
        var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

        rectangle.Width = w;
        rectangle.Height = h;

        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, y);

        rectangle.MouseDown += Rectangle_MouseDown;
        rectangle.MouseMove += Rectangle_MouseMove;

    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.GetPosition(rectangle);


        var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
        var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);


        var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
        var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

        rectangle.Width = w;
        rectangle.Height = h;

        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, y);
    }
```

Comment: You need to ask about what you want to accomplish in your program, not your chosen technique for accomplishing it.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @RobertHarvey in fact when i draw a button with wpf .I need to be able to resize it like having 4 points at each corner  of the button and be able to resize the button. this is what i have been wanted to ask.How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Weeks of searching i have found a solution.My boss wanted me to use rectangle instead of button 
so here's a solution of resizing a rectangle 
        private void MouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
             {

```
           //Button is an instance of a Rectangle.

           button = (sender as Rectangle); 

           Console.WriteLine("Dans le handler");

           do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Mouse.GetPosition(button));



                //MessageBox.Show("a cliqué");
                point = Mouse.GetPosition(button);


                //  Console.WriteLine(button.Width );

                if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cliqued for moving");
                    m_IsPressed = true;
                    isediting = false;
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
                else
                {
                    m_IsPressed = false;
                }

                if (point.X > 0 && point.X < button.Width && point.Y <= button.Height 
                && point.Y > button.Height - 10)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Cliqued for editing");
                    m_IsPressed = true;
                    isediting = true;

                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;

                }


        }
        while (button.IsMouseCaptured);
    }
```